# Track touch input on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, touch

I have a game board with 5x5 squares made of canvas drawrect:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int rowNo = 0; rowNo < nSquares; rowNo++) {
        paint.setColor(((rowNo & 1) == 0) ? colorA : colorB);
        for (int colNo = 0; colNo < nSquares; colNo++) {
            int left = colNo * squareWidth;
            int top = rowNo * squareWidth;

            Rect areaRect = new Rect(left, top, left + squareWidth, top + squareWidth);
            canvas.drawRect(areaRect, paint);


            paint.setColor((paint.getColor() == colorA) ? colorB : colorA);

            paint.setTextSize((float)(squareWidth*0.8));

            RectF bounds = new RectF(areaRect);
            String letter = "A";
            bounds.right = paint.measureText(letter, 0, letter.length());
            bounds.bottom = paint.descent() - paint.ascent();

            bounds.left += (areaRect.width() - bounds.right) / 2.0f;
            bounds.top += (areaRect.height() - bounds.bottom) / 2.0f;

            canvas.drawText(letter, bounds.left, bounds.top - paint.ascent(), paint);
        }
    }
```

I want to track touch input to get the squares the user are touching.. 
My attempt was

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Position: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

    int squareTouched = gameBoard.getSquare(x,y);
}
```

where getSquare is

```
public int getSquare(int x, int y) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for(int rowNo = 1; rowNo <= nSquares; rowNo++) {
        Log.i("Row", "Width: " + squareWidth + " rowNo: " + rowNo + " rowNo*squareW: " + rowNo*squareWidth + " y: " + y);
        if(rowNo*squareWidth > y)
        {
            row = rowNo;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int colNo = 1; colNo <= nSquares; colNo++) {
        if(colNo*squareWidth > x)
        {
            col = colNo;
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Row: " + row + " Col: " + col);
    return (row-1)*nSquares + col;
}
```

The problem is that the onTouchEvent getX and getY are referring to the screen 0,0, but when I draw the squares 0,0,0,0 is referring to the view origin? Am I right?
How can I get the input position relative to the game board view? 
Could it be a solution to get the view position in the screen and add/subtract this to the tochEvent x- and y position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the gameBoard().getX/Y() to return the correct values. My guess is that the action bar is excluded?

I now use `getLocationOnScreen`

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    int boardLocation[] = new int[2];
    gameBoard.getLocationOnScreen(boardLocation);

    int touchX = (int)event.getX();
    int touchY = (int)event.getY();

    int x = touchX - boardLocation[0];
    int y = touchY - boardLocation[1];

    int squareTouched = gameBoard.getSquare(x,y);
}
```

Which solved my issue..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `onDraw()` and `getSquare()` belong to `GameBoardView` and `onTouchEvent()` to its immediate parent. If so then the `onTouchEvent()` should be like this

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
          int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
          int x = (int)event.getX() - gameBoard.getX();
          int y = (int)event.getY() - gameBoard.getY();
          Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Position: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

          int squareTouched = gameBoard.getSquare(x, y);
    }
```

In a View x and y in both `onDraw()` and `onTouchEvent()` is relative to the View itself (Except when the View is scrolled). Since in your case `onTouchEvent()` belongs to parent and `onDraw()` to child, I used `View.getX()` and `getY()` to translate the coordinates. `View.getX()` returns the x position plus translationX of the View relative to its parent.